# How to achieve chains in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, common-table-expression

I have an attendance sheet that appears as follows:

[image: image here.]

I am trying to chain together the attendance of people (coded as ABC, DEF, etc.).
And I want the final result to appear like this: which shows the start and end dates of each segment/chain of attendance. If person A attends from 2021-01-01 to 2021-01-4, then it should show up as one row because it's one contiguous chain. I am not sure what to do or where to start. It's an odd way attendance data is saved.

[image: final output]

**More info:** I don't know if this matters, but I have up to 20 columns because our attendance max is 20 people. So it's up to Col20.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the record.  It is best to supply sample data as text.

This is a classic Gaps-and-Islands with a little twist.

Here we dynamically unpivot your data via a bit of JSON (without actually using dynamic SQL).

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=1b950af7353df099998d020afdc260af)**

```
;with cte as (
Select AttendanceDate
      ,B.*
      ,Grp = datediff(day,0,AttendanceDate) - dense_rank() over (partition by value order by AttendanceDate)
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select [Key]
                      ,Value
                 From OpenJson((Select A.* For JSON Path,Without_Array_Wrapper )) 
                 Where [Key] not in ('AttendanceDate')
             ) B
)
Select [Value]
      ,[Start]  = min(AttendanceDate)
      ,[End]    = max(AttendanceDate)
 From  cte
 Group By Value,Grp
```

**Returns**

```
Value   Start       End
ABC     2021-01-01  2021-01-04
DEF     2021-01-01  2021-01-03
GH      2021-01-02  2021-01-05
DEF     2021-01-07  2021-01-08
xx      2021-01-08  2021-01-10
zz      2021-01-08  2021-01-08
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I will try shortly, but I cannot run this in SSMS? I have to use JSON? (sorry if question is stupid)

Comment: @PowerBIBeginner Yes you can run this is SSMS  (I did).  The JSON portion required SQL Server 2016+.  What version on you running?

Comment: @PowerBIBeginner See edit.  I stripped out the demonstrative table variable

Comment: SSMS 2017 and this worked *beautifully*. Thanks a lot again. I need to really analyze it to understad it completely. but honestly I spent 2-3 hours and couldn't come up with anything.

Comment: just  one last question: did you use JSON because we don't know how many cols we may end up having? right now I have 20 cols, but it can change to 25, is this why you used JSON?

Comment: @PowerBIBeginner  Just run the query within the CTE.  This may illustrate how the Gaps-and-Islands is being formed.

Comment: @PowerBIBeginner Yes the JSON is being used due the variable number of columns.  If there is a known number of columns, there are more performant methods to unpivot.